# lightbox v2.10.0 how to make the entire image clickable not the magnifier

Tags: html, css, lightbox

As mentioned in the title I want the entire image to be clickable not only on the magnifier my website html5 thanks in advance for your help

I can't find how to do it, tried to hide the magnifier but couldn't make the image clickable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.